# Transform specific fields in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-collection

How do I Transform specific fields in Laravel?

For example:

```
$user = \Auth::User();
return [
    'user_id'  => $user->id,
    'articles' => $user->articles,
    'pages'    => $user->pages,
];
```

`$user->articles` will show the entries the `articles` table and `$user->pages` from the `pages` table.

In the User model, it would be defined something like that:

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Article::class);
}
```

I do not want to return all the fields from `$user->articles`, just id, name, and description. What is good way to transform this collection?

I would like to do something like:

```
'articles' => transformArticle($user->articles),
```

Answer (score 1):

In the relationship:

```
 return $this->hasMany('Article::class')->select(array('id', 'name','description'));
```

Or whenever you need it:

```
User::with(array('articles'=>function($query){
        $query->select('id','name','description');
    }))->get();
```

Comment: What about using methods from collection?

Comment: Something like `articles' => transformArticle($user->articles),`

Answer (score 0):

[Transformers](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/)

maybe you need this.